# Como faço o INNER JOIN neste caso?

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

Sou iniciante em PostgreSQL e preciso fazer um `INNER JOIN` pra relacionar dados de duas tabelas. Demorei bastante pra entender isso de `FOREIGN KEY`, mas fiz a referência certa no banco de dados. Agora, tenho uma aplicação C# e não sei como devo escrever o comando de leitura da tabela e relação dos dados.

Segue a estrutura atual do comando:

```
SELECT * FROM users_data WHERE user_id = {0}
```

O que me deixa em dúvida é onde colocar o `INNER JOIN`, o `AS`, e o `ON`. A tabela `users_data` possui uma coluna `user_type` e este valor deve ser alternado com a tabela `users_type`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deveria fazer assim:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users_data a
INNER JOIN users_type b ON b.id = a.user_type_id 
WHERE user_id = {0}
```

Isso levando em consideração que a sua tabela "users_data" possui o campo "user_type_id" que é a sua foreign key.

Para você entender melhor:

"INNER JOIN" é usando para você juntar duas tabelas. Você poderia ter vários "inner join" em uma query, nesse caso você está unindo várias tabelas em uma mesma consulta.

"ON" é usado logo junto a clausula INNER JOIN para indicar os campos que se relacionam.

"AS" é usado para renomear os campos da sua consulta. No caso aqui não foi usado.

Abs!

Answer (score 3):

Faça assim:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users_data 
     INNER JOIN user_type AS NomeAlias ON users_data.valor = NomeAlias.valor 
WHERE user_id = {0}
```

Onde `valor` seria a relação entre as tabelas, tal como uma ID ou algo parecido.

Outro Exemplo:

```
SELECT p.descricao, p.preco_custo, preco_venda, p.qtd_estoque, 
       p.qtd_estoque_minimo, marca.nome 
FROM produto as p
     INNER JOIN marca AS marca ON marca.id = p.id_marca
ORDER BY marca.nome
```

Porém precisa ser visto qual tipo de relação você deseja fazer.

Há diferenças entre `Join`, `Left Join`, `Right Join` e `Inner Join`.

Comment: `join` neste caso não é idêntico ao `inner join`? Se não, você tem a documentação que fala dessa diferença no Postgres?

Comment: Na realidade o `Join` é uma formar simplificada de `Inner Join`, deixado de um modo um pouco mais claro na leitura. Principalmente quando há outras relações.

Comment: seu último parágrafo não ficou claro em respeito a isso :-] talvez fosse melhor tentar esclarecer isso no texto

Comment: Sim, vou melhorar depois sou novato nisso. então tenho muito que melhor.

Comment: somos todos novatos em busca do aprendizado ;-)